# jQuery Plugin, can't target ID

Tags: jquery

as you can see i'm applying a function to an ID like so:

```
$("map_canvas").multimap({ });
```

And this is the function, however `this` is displaying `[object Object]` and I think it's getting the window, not my DIV with that ID...

```
(function($) {

        $.fn.multimap = function( options ) {

            var container = $( this );
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

Still getting an error when I try to use `this` like so:

```
(function($) {

        $.fn.multimap = function( options ) {



            // This is the easiest way to have default options.
            var settings = $.extend({
                // These are the defaults.
                locations: [
                    ['Address Title', 'Add Address Here', {lat: 53.008756, lng: -2.181422}]
                ],
                iconSize: { width: 70, height: 70 },
                zoom: 10,
                mapType: 'ROADMAP'

            }, options );

            var map;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            // Override handles
            var i_iconSize = settings.iconSize;
            if (settings.iconSize.constructor !== Object) { 
                i_iconSize = { width: settings.iconSize, height: settings.iconSize };
            }


            function initialize() {
                var lat = parseFloat(settings.locations[0][2]['lat']);
                var lng = parseFloat(settings.locations[0][2]['lng']);
                var i_mapType;

                switch(settings.mapType) {
                    case "ROADMAP":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
                        break;
                    case "SATELLITE":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;
                        break;
                    case "HYBRID":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;
                        break;
                    case "TERRAIN":
                        i_mapType = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;
                        break;
                }

                map = new google.maps.Map(
                this, {
                    // Initial center point, changes ones the markers are added though
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),

                    // This doesn't seme to work, seems to just scale to fit all markers in at the moment
                    zoom: settings.zoom,

                    // Change the map type, not sure what the others are called
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });

                for (i = 0; i < (settings.locations).length; i++) {
                    createMarker(settings.locations, i);
                }
            }
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: Is map_canvas is an ID of div

Comment: Yeah, map_canvas is the ID of a Div.

Comment: Then you should have used `$("#map_canvas")`.

Comment: Yes. It should be #map_canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used `#` before id name  In JQuery  **ex:**  `$("#idname")` select element with `id="idname"`

If you used the class then used `.` before the class name **ex:** `$(".classname")` Select all elements with `class="classname"`

```
$("map_canvas").multimap({ });
```

TO

```
$("#map_canvas").multimap({ });
```

Comment: God damn it, what a silly mistake! However this still isn't working, getting an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("map_canvas").multimap({ });
```

Should be

```
$("#map_canvas").multimap({ });
```

More about jquery selectors http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp